# Why can't I directly access table.AutoFilter.filters.Item(1).On and set it to False?

Tags: excel, filtering, excel-2013, vba

Normally when trying to figure out how to access a value or attribute of an object in VBA, I can open the Locals Window and look through the children of the object in question and drill down until i find the value I'm looking for.  For instance, if I wanted to get the second cell/column of a named listrow a simple search through the Local Window reveals that something like

```
selectedRow.Range.Value2(1, 2)
```

should get me the answer.

So all that being true, why doesn't a statement like the following work?

```
table.AutoFilter.Filters.Item(1).On = False
```

Assuming i wanted to remove the filter from just the first column of a set table object, the previous statement should work, at least according to the Locals Window and Excel VBA documenation.  Or something like:

```
table.AutoFilter.Filters.Item(3).Criteria1 = "SearchString"
```

Should let me update the Criteria for the third column in my table.  Its clearly marked with the values populated in the Locals Window, the VBA editor happily offers each level in the auto complete while typing it out and yet every level after 'AutoFilter' throws an error when attempting to run.

So why are these attributes provided/suggested if you can't use them? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Excel 2010 and 2013 the `AutoFilter.Filter.Ttem.On` property is read-only. So that answers your first question.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197843%28v=office.15%29.aspx

The same is true for the `AutoFilter.Filter.Ttem.Criteria1` property. Which answers the second one.

(I didn't know either of these things before now, so thanks for asking.)

Comment: I see that link isn't so much help as I can't drill down to the `On` or `Criteria1` properties. You can get to it from VBA help though.

Comment: Yeah missed those two key words when i reading through the documentation. Pity though, having those work would make life a lot easier instead of the hack-job way VBA currently allows filtering and sorting.